# Get UIImageView's width and height programmatically issue

Tags: xcode, swift, image, width

i'm trying to retrieve the width and height of an image view on different size of iPhone with the following code

```
print(self.imageLength.bounds.size.height)
print(self.imageLength.bounds.size.width)
```

yup, it return the same value 128.0 on iPhone 5, iPhone 6, iPhone 6 plus. but the UIImage shows on interface does changed according to different phone size. Does anyone why?

Here is the image constraints

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this

```
let imgWidth = myImageView.layer.frame.width
let imgHeight = myImageView.layer.frame.height

print(imgWidth)
print(imgHeight)
```

Comment: Hi, yah i have tried this, but it doesn't make any changes

Comment: You are setting the constraint according to the screen or had you accidentally set the fixed width and height

Comment: @S.Wei and one more, where did you put this code at? It will work on `viewDidAppear` but not in `viewDidLoad` because it is still loading, you can try run the print after the view had appear

Comment: Hi i updated my question with the picture constraints.

Comment: @S.Wei where did you put your `print`?

Comment: oh yah, i put it in viewDidLoad at first, it doesn't work then i put it to viewDidAppear and it works like a cham! Thank you very much!